# Google Map unable to find the theme

Tags: android, android-mapview

Why eclipse shows "Failed to find style 'mapViewStyle' in current theme" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are working on 3.0 sdk. I also have the same problem but 2.1,2.2 and 2.3.3 works fine . so for now better change to lesser versions and check out if they are working.you can change the sdk version from Graphics layout .